# Inside Visual Studio Code (macOS), Cyrillic typefaces are shown with a different font, why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When VSCode deals with two languages inside of the editor (the main font has the support of Cyrillic alphabet though), the Russian language shown with a different font, how to get the same font for Russian and English as well?

Example:

```
<title>"Писатели Якутии"</title>
```

Is it because your main font does not contain the required UTF subset, so a fall back font is used, or what? If it is true, how to add the required UTF subset to VSCode?

System: macOS Mojave, the latest version of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What font are you expecting to see? If the chosen font doesn't have the characters, it usually just shows ▯ or something like that.

Comment: The answer is, thanks to Reddit:

1) Just use a font with the Cyrillic alphabet as my main font

2) Add preferred Cyrillic font second in the list of fonts in ```fontFamily```, as in

```"editor.fontFamily": "fontOne, fontTwo"```,

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, thanks to Reddit:

1) Just use a font with the Cyrillic alphabet as my main font;

2) Add preferred Cyrillic font second in the list of fonts in `fontFamily`, as in:

`"editor.fontFamily": "fontOne, fontTwo"`,