# Fallback font size is VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to specify fallback font size?

My favorite font doesn't support Cyrillic and the fallback font looks bigger than usual.

Comment: alternative way to solve problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123847/inside-visual-studio-code-macos-cyrillic-typefaces-are-shown-with-a-different?rq=1